# Filter only unique values from an array of object javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects i want to filter only the unique style and is not repeated .

```
const arrayOfObj = [ {name:'a' , style:'p'} , {name:'b' , style:'q'} , {name:'c' , style:'q'}]

result expected : [ {name:'a' , style:'p'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution in O(n) time complexity. You can iterate all entries to track how often an entry occurs. And then use the `filter()` function to filter the ones that occur only once.

```js
const arrayOfObj = [
  { name: "a", style: "p" },
  { name: "b", style: "q" },
  { name: "c", style: "q" },
]

const styleCount = {}

arrayOfObj.forEach((obj) => {
  styleCount[obj.style] = (styleCount[obj.style] || 0) + 1
})

const res = arrayOfObj.filter((obj) => styleCount[obj.style] === 1)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: It seems like this loses "name": "c".

Answer (score 3):

On of the possible solutions depending on your performance / readability needs can be:

```
arrayOfObj.filter(a => arrayOfObj.filter(obj => obj.style === a.style).length === 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use splice when you find the existing item and remove it

```js
const arrayOfObj = [{
  name: 'a',
  style: 'p'
}, {
  name: 'b',
  style: 'q'
}, {
  name: 'c',
  style: 'q'
}]

const result = arrayOfObj.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(y => y.style === x.style);
  if (index >= 0) {
    acc.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    acc.push(x);
  }
  return acc;

}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You reduce it. Check if in the array already an element with the same style exists and remove it from the accumulator otherwise push it to the accumulator

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "a", style: "p" },
  { name: "b", style: "q" },
  { name: "c", style: "q" }
];

  let result = arr.reduce((a,v) => {
     let i = a.findIndex(el => el.style === v.style);
     if(i !== -1) {
        a.splice(i,1);
        return a;
     }
     a.push(v)
     return a;
  },[])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in O(n) time complexity. You can iterate all entries to track how often an entry occurs. And then use the `filter()` function to filter the ones that occur only once.

```js
const arrayOfObj = [ {name:'a' , style:'p'} , {name:'b' , style:'q'} , {name:'c' , style:'q'}];

let count = {};

arrayOfObj.forEach(({style}) => {
    count[style] = (count[style] || 0) + 1;
});

let result = arrayOfObj.filter(({style}) => count[style] === 1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a one liner answer too if you are using lodash library
(uniqBy(array, iteratee))

```
const arr = [
  { name: "a", style: "p" },
  { name: "b", style: "q" },
  { name: "c", style: "q" }
];
let result = _.uniqBy(arrayOfObj,'style')
console.log(result)
```